# Does selenoid has dashboard like zalenium? and which one is more recommended to use?

Tags: selenoid, zalenium

I am new to selenoid. On my linux system selenoid and selenoid-ui services are up and running. I am able to run test cases on selenoid also able to view videos and logs on http://:4444/video/ and http://:4444/logs/. 
Do we have a dashboard where we will have total no of test cases executed, passed, failed, logs etc.
As per the links gone through, most of the people have supported use of selenoid over zalenium. why? the url which it provides such as http://:4444/video/ and http://:4444/logs/ are also not well designed.

---

---

Comment: Have you seen Selenoid UI? http://github.com/aerokube/selenoid-ui

Comment: Regarding the dashboard - it's not Selenoid responsibility to show you test cases statistics. Use something like Allure report (https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2) for that.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Do we have a dashboard where we will have total no of test cases
>      executed, passed, failed, logs etc?

The selenoid dashboard doesn't have any option to set test result, test counts etc.
It only shows videos, logs and the browsers on which the tests are run.
The [selenoid-ui](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid-ui) is open source, so you can customize the dashboard by adding some reports.
Please refer to [selenoid-ui](http://aerokube.com/selenoid-ui/latest/) for development and contrubiting.

> 2. As per the links gone through, most of the people have supported use
>      of selenoid over zalenium. why?

If you are going to use many versions of browsers(chrome, opera, firefox), the selenoid is preferable.

Zalenium supports only two latest versions of chrome and firefox, but it also works with could base testing tools(browserstack, saucelabs etc).